# How do I manually unwrap wrapped coins (like wbtc not WETH)

Tags: erc-20, wrapped-tokens

Im not interested in just swapping the coins on uniswap, I want to unlock the value of wrapped tokens.

I have a number of coins similar to WBTC that I want to manually unwrap to get the BTC back. Is there a way to do this? Is it even possible?

As the title says, not WETH, which is trivial to unwrap, but other blockchain coins, can it be done, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't, or at least not easily.

For instance: wBTC has actual BTCs under BitGo's custody. If a wBTC token holder would like to get the corresponding BTC it would have to start an offchain process to do so.

Other tokens sit behind blockchain bridges or complex protocols, or even simply centralized authorities that provide a collateral. It might be possible depending on the token, but I wouldn't definitely count on it.